# #golang Starting go run

Tags: golang

Every time I start my PC, Go is automatically inactive, so I have to extract it every day.

What I should do with that problem? I want Go to work constantly.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on what you mean by "extract"? Once Go is installed it does not get removed ... unless you are running Ubuntu in a Live Session only 

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to start it automatically. Retype the command that you use to start `Go`. This time, however add the following to the end:

```
YOUR_COMMAND >> ~/.bashrc
```

Where `COMMAND` is the original command that you use. Next, if you need to boot `Go` still, type the following into the terminal:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

The file to which you just wrote your command, `~/.bashrc`, runs each time the system boots. `Go` should automatically start on boot from here forward.